# Android: How to crop an image using Picasso?

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I want to use the Picasso Image library for Android to crop an image – not resize it.

To be more specific, I want to load an image and then take a rectangular piece of it with coordinates `(x,y)`, width `w`, and height `h`:

```
Original Image
------------------------------
|                            |
|    (x,y)                   |
|      ------------          |
|      |          |          |
|      | Cropped  |          |
|      |  Image   | h        |
|      |          |          |
|      |          |          |
|      ------------          |
|           w                |
------------------------------
```

Then, I want to load this rectangular piece of the original image into an `ImageView`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Picasso's transform function for that. It allows you to pass your own method to make the required changes to the `Bitmap` drawable:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(R.drawable.sample)  // the image you want to load
       .transform(new Transformation() {
           @Override
           public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
               Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(source,x,y,w,h);   // the actual cropping
               source.recycle();   // recycle the source bitmap to avoid memory problems
               return result;
           }

           @Override
           public String key() {
               return x+","+y+","+w+","+h;  // some id unique for the transformation you do
           }
       })
       .into(findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);    // load the cropped image into your image view
```